# "TimeSpan?" не содержит определения "TotalMinutes"

Tags: c#, .net, ооп, backend

Программа простая, прототип бэк-энда для киоска парковки. Надо посчитать время выезда машины с парковки, но почему-то при попытке подсчитать разницу в минутах с одним из полей выдаёт ошибку:

```
public bool TryLeaveParkingWithTicket(int ticketNumber, out ParkingSession session)
{

    session = ActiveParkingSessions[ticketNumber];

    double parkingTime;

    if(session.PaymentDt != null)
    {
        parkingTime = (DateTime.Now - session.PaymentDt).TotalMinutes;
    }
    else {
        parkingTime = (DateTime.Now - session.EntryDt).TotalMinutes;
    }

    if(parkingTime < freeLeavePeriod) {
        session.ExitDt = DateTime.Now;
        ActiveParkingSessions.Remove(session);
        PastParkingSessions.Add(session);

        return true;
    }
    else {
        session = null;
    }

    return false;

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Текст ошибки: "TimeSpan?" не содержит определения "TotalMinutes", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "TotalMinutes", принимающий тип TimeSpan? в качестве первого аргумента (возможно пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку). " ошибка в строке

```
parkingTime = (DateTime.Now - session.PaymentDt).TotalMinutes;
```

Сам класс сессии:

```
class ParkingSession
    {
        private DateTime entryDt;
        private DateTime? paymentDt;
        private DateTime? exitDt;
        private decimal? totalPayment;
        private string carPlateNumber;
        private int ticketNumber;


        // Date and time of arriving at the parking
        public DateTime EntryDt { 
            get { return entryDt; }
            set {
                this.entryDt = value;
            }
        }

        // Date and time of payment for the parking
        public DateTime? PaymentDt { 
            get { return paymentDt; }
            set {
                this.paymentDt = value;
            } 
        }
        // Date and time of exiting the parking
        public DateTime? ExitDt {
            get { return exitDt; }
            set { 
                this.exitDt = value;
            } 
        }
        // Total cost of parking
        public decimal? TotalPayment { 
            get { return totalPayment; }
            set{
                this.totalPayment = value;
            }
        }
        // Plate number of the visitor's car
        public string CarPlateNumber { 
            get { return carPlateNumber; }
            set{
                this.carPlateNumber = value;
            }
        }
        // Issued printed ticket
        public int TicketNumber { 
            get { return ticketNumber; } 
            set{
                this.ticketNumber = value;
            }
        }

        public ParkingSession(DateTime _EntryDt, string _CarPlateNumber, int _TicketNumber)
        {
            EntryDt = _EntryDt;
            TicketNumber = _TicketNumber;
            CarPlateNumber = _CarPlateNumber;
            TotalPayment = null;
            ExitDt = null;
            PaymentDt = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А `TotalMinutes` Ваш или заимствованый? В него заглянуть поглубже можно?

Comment: к сожалению метод не мой, да и вряд ли в нём дело, скорее всего это из-за типа с вопросительным знаком в конце

Comment: А вы знакомы с авто-свойствами? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime? PaymentDt` - это [nullable DateTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/), в нем может лежать либо DateTime, либо null. Соответственно, при вычитании

```
DateTime.Now - session.PaymentDt
```

вы получаете nullable TimeSpan - в котором лежит или TimeSpan, или null.

Если вы точно знаете, что к этому моменту PaymentDt у вас не null - явно напишите в коде обращение именно к DateTime:

```
parkingTime = (DateTime.Now - session.PaymentDt.Value).TotalMinutes;
```

Если при этом оно может быть null при обычной работе - добавьте проверку на == null чуть выше и напишите код для случая, когда PaymentDt не задан.